# Magento 2 How to flush javascript cache?

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, cache

I rewrote the code in validation.js.
It was successfull,the new text has appeared on the site and now i want to change it again but this time its not changing on the frontend.

I tried to flush cache,static content,css/javascript.
Trought SSH i flushed the cache,reindexed the datas,used setup:upgrade and setup:static-contend:deploy as well.
Also used ccleaner just to be sure.

I also tried to upload the old file from backup but nothing.

Thank you

Comment: Clear your browser cache too.

Comment: That is what ccleaner did.